# How to read All Mail on IMAP Gmail with the Alpine / Pine e-mail client?

Tags: command-line, email, imap, gmail, alpine-mail

How is the "Incoming-Folders Collection" made to [include](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.mail.pine/c/OhytyMC355A/m/rV3DaT0HAgAJ) the "all mail" IMAP folder?

Currently, the ".pinerc" has the inbox as:

```
# Path of (local or remote) INBOX, e.g. ={mail.somewhere.edu}inbox
# Normal Unix default is the local INBOX (usually /var/spool/mail/$USER).
inbox-path={imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=saunders.nicholas@gmail.com}INBOX



# Over-rides default path for saved-msg folder, e.g. =saved-messages (using 1st
# folder collection dir) or ={host2}saved-mail or ="" (to suppress saving).
# Default: saved-messages (Unix) or SAVEMAIL.MTX (PC) in default collection.
default-saved-msg-folder=[Gmail]/All Mail
```

But I want to be able to open that "All Mail" folder as the inbox and other folders are [available](https://alpineapp.email/pine/pine-info/collections/incoming-folders/) through `Alpine` from the console.